# /sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument - how to solve this error?

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, windows-10, shared-folders

I'm trying to share a folder between ,a host, windows 10 and ,a guest, ubuntu 16.04.
I have already created a folder in linux and set up inside the virtual box.
Inside `/media` I have created a folder called `songs`.
now I'm trying to mount a volume using the following:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf sf_shareubuntu/ songs/
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
```

how do I solve this error?

Comment: Have you read official documentation ["5.3.1. Manual Mounting"](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#sf_mount_manual)?

Comment: There is no location like `sf_shareubuntu/ songs/` it ought to be `sharename  /media/songs/`

Answer (score 2):

The normal way to get that done from the link provided by Norbert

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint
```

So your command should be

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename /media/songs
```

To mount a shared folder during boot, add the following entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
sharename   /media/songs   vboxsf   defaults  0   0
```

**The sharename comes from the Windows hosts' sharename**

Answer (score 2):

```
2
The normal way to get that done from the link provided by Norbert
sudo mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename mountpoint
So your command should be
sudo mount -t vboxsf [-o OPTIONS] sharename /media/songs
```

Unfortunately, this is not resolve, look:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf INSTALL /media/sf_INSTALL
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
```

This happens when vbox-guest-utils version inside virtualbox is different from host version. Sharename isn't properly ported between the host system and the virtualbox system.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Upgrading VM Box and starting the whole shared folder process again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got such error in guest, when I tried to mount shared folder, pointing to symbolic link on the host. Solved it by changing it to actual target folder on host instead.

Answer (score 0):

Update all virtualbox-guest packages, atleast that's what worked for me.i wasn't able to figure the exact package though.

i listed all packages:

```
virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 6.1.38-1~ubuntu1.22.04.1 all [installed]
virtualbox-guest-utils-hwe/jammy-updates,now 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
virtualbox-guest-utils/jammy-updates,now 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1 amd64 [residual-config]
virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe/jammy-updates,now 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1 amd64 [installed]
virtualbox-guest-x11/jammy-updates 6.1.38-dfsg-3~ubuntu1.22.04.1 amd64
```

then updated each package individually

```
The package name is the name before '/', for virtualbox-guest additions iso it is "virtualbox-guest-additions-iso".
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue where the Guest OS's version was not *supported* by the loaded Guest Additions version.

I found this out by reading VirtualBox's [Changelog](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) and seeing a note under a newer VBox version that Guest support was added for my Guest's Kernel.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.1#v28

> - Linux Host and Guest: Introduced initial support for kernels 5.14 and 5.15

Installing the newer Guest Additions worked*, and I was able to get Folders mounted again.

*I will state that installing Guest Additions that are newer than VBox is not recommended (only the opposite case (older GA, newer VBox) is supported/expected to work, as per https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#guestadd-intro).  In my particular case, this was on a personal VM used for running Linux-specific tools, and the VBox version was only old due to other dependencies that I, ironically, was in the process of sorting out so that I could upgrade VBox.