# Shared folder mounting failed

Tags: mount, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am using Ubuntu 64 bit with a virtual box and I shared a folder between Windows (host) and Ubuntu.

In the virtual box configuration I defined the shared folder as follow:

```
Name    (Windows) Path           Access

Linux   C:\Users\...             Full
```

In Ubuntu, I mounted the folder with the following code:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf Linux /home/julien/... (Path in linux)
```

I have had this configuration for a year and it worked well. Unfortunately, I have not used Ubuntu for 1 or 2 months and today I have the following error when I went to mount the folder:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
```

Of course, both folders in Windows and linux have not changed. I tried to create a new virtual box with linux mint and I shared the same folder with the preceding steps: It works perfectly on linux mint.

Do you have any idea what happened ? Has something changed with Ubuntu recently ?

I read this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105503/sbin-mount-vboxsf-mounting-failed-with-the-error-invalid-argument-how-to-so) but it did not help.

Comment: You may need to update (or reinstall) VBoxGuestAdditions software on the guest OS. You haven't specified any host and guest **operating system versions**, but the latest VBoxGuestAdditions software is 6.1.32: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.32/VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.32.iso

Comment: I am using Virtual box 6.1.16. I will try to update the VBoxGuestAdditions software with the link you gave.

Comment: It works now, with the last verson of  VBoxGuestAdditions software. Thank you for your help.